# Should I be flagging "incorrect" comments from flags or reviews as Not Constructive?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

I was reading [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/2415822) on Meta Stack Overflow and saw something interesting:

> TL;DR: Review carefully. Don't delete everything. Deletion is for things that actually aren't answers, *not* for low-quality answers or "wrong" answers. Flag incorrect comments from review as "not constructive".

I recently asked a Pokemon Go question [Why is there a 0 CP egg in this gym?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/282375/88253), which some users misconstrued as a question on how to exploit the game.  This was not my goal with the question, and I changed the title of my post to reflect that I was asking for information and was not trying to break any rules.  One user voted to close the question as off-topic, and I flagged their comment as "not constructive" since I believed my question to be on-topic.  The flag was declined.

If I feel that a question has been flagged incorrectly (I put incorrect in quotes in the question title, since this can be subjective), should I mark the comment from review as "not constructive?"

Comment: For what it's worth, the question is sitting at 1 of 5 required close votes, and is likely cleared from the queue.

Comment: @Unionhawk I believe it's still in the queue, since the post's [timeline](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/282375/timeline) has not been updated to reflect that it went through it.  Again, using my question as an example but looking for a general discussion.

Comment: As of 10 minutes ago, my question left the CV queue with 3 leave open votes.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I be flagging “incorrect” comments from flags or reviews as Not Constructive?

No.  You are saying incorrect because you don't agree.  However, others may feel that the question is off-topic, and have given their reason(s) in comments.

The comments are constructive because it helps people who review the questions in the review queues.  Without those comments it is harder to see how it got into the review queue in the first place, or how other reviewers are voting on the question.

Comment: As the mod who dismissed the flag, this was my reasoning. Thanks for answering before I could get to it :-)

Comment: Clearly 3 others did not agree either, as the question left the queue without gaining any additional close votes.

Comment: You can also see how others are reviewing the questions without the comments by looking at the vote counts on the close reasons.

Comment: @JAL - Firstly, whether people agree or not with the comment, its existent is constructive for others to review it in the queue.  That is why such comments won't be removed for being "not constructive".  On the second point, that count just shows other votes, and not the initial flag reason.  I don't think you get a count if people select the no comment reason.